# protect and unprotect a checkbox with a warning give me a erroneous behaviour

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, data-protection, spreadsheet-protection

The purpose is to be able to execute some code by checking the Checkbox. `Checked` visually remains you  that the process is already executed. If you Uncheck you are warned of consequences to do it.

Checking a checkbox creates a protection `protection.setWarningOnly(true)`, but unchecking `protection.remove()` does not erase this protection, as programmed in the AppsScript code.

I reduced the problem to a minimum Sheet, with a minimum code.
the sheet is only a cell ("A1" in the example) with a checkbox. (You can Add More...)
and a trigger 'OnEdit' to protectCells(e).

```
function protectCell(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var eRange = e.range;
  var protection = eRange.protect();
  var isChecked = eRange.getValue();

  //Browser.msgBox("Checkbox state: " + isChecked);

  if (isChecked) {
    // Lock the cell when the checkbox is checked
    protection.setWarningOnly(true);
    //Browser.msgBox("Protection set with warning.");
  } else {
    // Unlock the cell when the checkbox is unchecked
    protection.remove();
    //Browser.msgBox("Protection removed.");
  }
}
```

you can test it at : [1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E1DmIg6DQ5Ntp7ib4iA7BcY159OYyY-Qwf0ko8i2F7g/edit#gid=0)

Duplicated protections[image]

Comment: Please, what is the problem with the question that make it to be closed? thanks!

Comment: See second code here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection Loop through range protections to remove them... There are couple other issues. If the question is reopened, I'll try to add a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As written [in the doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect), calling `range.protect()` duplicates the protection:

  > If the range is already protected, this method creates a new protected range that overlaps the existing one.

  Therefore call `.protect()` only after removing all existing protections. Use the description as key to avoid removing protections not set by the script.

```
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function protectCell(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const eRange = e.range;
  const thisProtectionDescription = 'protectedByScript1689';
  const isChecked = eRange.isChecked();

  //Don't run for all sheets
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'Sheet1') return;

  //Remove all existing RANGE protections with description=protectionDescription
  ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).forEach(
    (protection) => {
      if (protection.getDescription() === thisProtectionDescription)
        protection.remove();
    }
  );

  if (isChecked && eRange.getA1Notation() === 'A1') {
    // Lock the cell when the checkbox is checked
    const protection = eRange.protect();
    protection.setDescription(thisProtectionDescription);
    protection.setWarningOnly(true);
    //Browser.msgBox("Protection set with warning.");
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks! other way it will be difficult for me to imagine this curious way.

Comment: @GSerraG Consider accepting the answer by clicking  the checkmark on the left of this post, if it solved your problem.